# Does it make a difference to copy & paste functions vs. making 1 function with many parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in javascript + jQuery, and I have a site right here...

http://matiny.altervista.org/VI/vice-beauty/

In it, I copy & paste this type of function. What it does is it changes the images' file path based off your click.

```
//Bottoms

    $('div').on('click', 'div:contains("Low Waist Jeans")', function () {
        $('.model img:nth-child(4)').attr('src', 'beauty/4-bottoms/jeans.png');
        displayTopBot();
    });

    $('div').on('click', 'div:contains("High Waist Jeans")', function () {
        $('.model img:nth-child(4)').attr('src', 'beauty/4-bottoms/jeans2.png');
        displayTopBot();
    });

    $('div').on('click', 'div:contains("Yoga Pants")', function () {
        $('.model img:nth-child(4)').attr('src', 'beauty/4-bottoms/yoga.png');
        displayTopBot();
    });
```

I was thinking about going back and renaming the 30 something files so that they have the same name as the buttons. That way, I could set it up that you click the buttons, and I transfer the name on the button (using .text() and toLowerCase()) to the file path. Besides that, maybe you could help me write the code smarter.

Comment: Yes, go ahead and do it. I would say there is nothing wrong in improving as long as it works well for you. Although I wonder if this question fits into SO.

Comment: It seems appropriate, as it relates to programming techniques. The site I linked is not a real site or anything, but it's good to follow proper practices.

Answer (score 1):

Repetition/Duplication of code is always bad for software, Code Duplication leads to many problems, ie. Bugs,unreadable code. It is a code smell.

The code you have written above is full of these problems and it leads to code smell. Definitely you need to move it in a single common function.

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor that to make it reusable and maintainable.  Several approaches, data properties, something generated from the server etc.

- This is somewhat opinionated and up to the environment you work within.
- I would say generally it is NOT the best to use a "description" as a reference, but that depends on your environment;

Since this is about "possible" code refactor, let's provide one example.

**For example here is ONE possible refactor**

I assume a complex object from the server/somewhere represented here as `myApp.data.pantsimages`, somewhat complex object array;

Using a simple `lookup` function and some data from an object in your JavaScript code, *it could come from the server, ajax etc, or be hard coded as this example*. BUT better than multiple locations and totally embedded in the code base, what if someone changes a description?

Some reference HTML (just for this example) See how I cheated and change descriptions?

```
<div class="mythings">
  <div class="selectors" data-myref="lwjeans">
    Low Waist Jeans
  </div>
  <div class="selectors" data-myref="ypants">
    Yoga Pants
  </div>
  <div class="selectors" data-myref="ypants">
    Yoga Workout Pants
  </div>
  <div class="selectors" data-myref="hwjeans">
    High Waist Jeans
  </div>
  <div class="selectors" data-myref="hwjeans">
    High Waist Girls Jeans
  </div>
</div>
```

First a set of functions (I included some "extra" ones as simple examples you might put in a application script:(this should work even in really old browsers like IE6; could be refactored to use newer stuff if you ONLY have newer ones)

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.arrayObj = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  }
};
```

Now we put some data in an object we know of (avoids some global namespace pollution) using our `myApp` object created above.

```
myApp.data = {
  pantsimages: [{
    ref: "lwjeans",
    description: "High Wast Jeans",
    image: "'beauty/4-bottoms/jeans.png"
  }, {
    ref: "hwjeans",
    description: "High Wast Jeans",
    image: "beauty/4-bottoms/jeans2.png"
  }, {
    ref: "lwjeans",
    description: "High Wast Jeans",
    image: "beauty/4-bottoms/yoga.png"
  }],
  modelref: ".model img:nth-child(4)",
  imageref: "myref"
};
```

Now we can use that in a function similar to yours.  The `lookup` gets the object with the referenced "ref" object, with comments

```
$('div.mythings').on('click', '.selectors', function() {
  // get reference from clicked element (see markup)
  var myref = $(this).data(myApp.data.imageref);
  // lookup an image in my pantsimages object based on the reference by the "ref" property
  var myimage = myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myApp.data.pantsimages, myref , "ref", true).image;
  // set the src atrribute with the image using the selector in the data called modelref
  $(myApp.data.modelref).attr('src', myimage );
  displayTopBot();
});
```

Compacted version of above:

```
$('div.mythings').on('click', '.selectors', function() {
  $(myApp.data.modelref).attr('src', myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myApp.data.pantsimages, $(this).data(myApp.data.imageref), "ref", true));
  displayTopBot();
});
```

Now see here where we can add a NEW function group, and use it making our code more modular:

```
myApp.func{
  getImage:function(me){
      $(myApp.data.modelref).attr('src', myApp.arrayObj.lookup(myApp.data.pantsimages, $(me).data(myApp.data.imageref), "ref", true));
  }
};

$('div.mythings').on('click', '.selectors', function() {
   myApp.func.getImage(this);
  displayTopBot();
});
```

See HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/pmq64zpw/3/ where I quickly refactored the above to create a "shoes image" functionality.

This is all untested and may contain issues/bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data attribute on your divs:

```
$('div').on('click', 'div.img-btn', function () {
    var imgSrc = $(this).data('imgsrc');
    $('.model img:nth-child(4)').attr('src', imgSrc);
    displayTopBot();
});
```